# Mysql order by varchar mixed value

Tags: mysql

I have this values in Mysql table:

```
id    name (varchar 100)
1     CHANCE EAU TENDRE
2     CRISTALLE
3     EGOISTE
4     1- COCO
5     1- COCO NOIR
6     ALLURE
7     2- N.5
8     3- COCO HOMME
9     - COCO CHANEL
...
```

I can't figure out how order by name, I've tried to search without success but didn't works.
Of course, I want **ALLURE** before **CHANCE EAU TENDRE**

Expected result:

```
| id  | name              |
| --- | ----------------- |
| 6   | ALLURE            |
| 1   | CHANCE EAU TENDRE |
| 4   | 1- COCO           |
| 9   | - COCO CHANEL     |
| 8   | 3- COCO HOMME     |
| 5   | 1- COCO NOIR      |
| 2   | CRISTALLE         |
| 3   | EGOISTE           |
| 7   | 2- N.5            |
```

My tests:

```
SELECT * FROM brands ORDER BY CAST(name AS UNSIGNED), name ASC
```

---

```
SELECT * FROM brands ORDER BY convert(`name`, decimal) ASC
```

---

```
SELECT * FROM brands ORDER BY (name * 1) ASC
```

Those doesn't works because mixed value (number + char).

EDIT: 
add this link for understand better the question:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8f6e9a/2

Comment: What is `brand`column inside the query? Shouldn't it be `name`? As in `SELECT * FROM brands ORDER BY name ASC`

Comment: `order by name` will have result ALLURE before CHANCE EAU TENDRE. So what is the question?

Comment: your question is not clear  ... why you are not using ORDER BY name ??

Comment: i doubt you get this working you said there are alot of cases (i assume more then you show now) on a now deleted answer..

Comment: @andreah What is your expected result?

Comment: But what do the numbers in `1- COCO` and `2- N.5` for example mean?

Comment: @RaymondNijland their database is a mess, but I can't change values.

Comment: Fair enough, but what are the expected results?  Or logic for sorting here?

Comment: I think @forpas answer could works. I don't think it could be better, there are so many cases.

Comment: Can anyone tell me about downvote? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you want to sort first by the brand name and then by the number at the start:

```
select * from brands
order by 
  trim(trim(leading '-' from trim(trim(leading name + 0 from name)))),
  name + 0
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rhnVwNYGm7Eo8cAkbz1KYB/2).
Results:

```
| id  | name              |
| --- | ----------------- |
| 6   | ALLURE            |
| 1   | CHANCE EAU TENDRE |
| 4   | 1- COCO           |
| 9   | - COCO CHANEL     |
| 8   | 3- COCO HOMME     |
| 5   | 1- COCO NOIR      |
| 2   | CRISTALLE         |
| 3   | EGOISTE           |
| 7   | 2- N.5            |
```